# Route.get() requires a callback function

Tags: node.js

Want to learn node.js, trying to create an app, that would interact with database, but got something wrong ... When I am running it, I am getting an error -

`Uncaught Error Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Number]`

I have that folder structure:

```
includes/database/createConnection.js
includes/routings.js
app.js
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const appConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./configs/appconfig.json")))
const routings = require(path.resolve("./includes/routings.js"));

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.get('/testdb',routings.testdb());
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${appConfig.host}:${appConfig.port}`);
});
```

routings.js

```
function testdb(){
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const testing = require(path.resolve("./includes/database/createConnection.js"));

    let connection = testing.connectToDatabase();
    connection.query("SELECT GETDATE()",function (error, results, fields){
        if(error) throw error;

        return results[0].solution;
    });
    console.log("Got through")
    return 123;
}

module.exports = {testdb}
```

createConnection.js

```
function connectToDatabase(){
    const fs = require('fs')
    const mysql = require('mysql')
    const path = require('path');

    const dbConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./configs/dbconfig.json")))

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: dbConfig.host,
        port: dbConfig.port,
        user: dbConfig.username,
        password: dbConfig.password,
        database: dbConfig.database
    })

    connection.connect(function(error){
        if(error) throw error;
    });
    return connection;
}

module.exports = {connectToDatabase}
```

As I can see in debug, it happens after routings.js is finished

Answer (score 0):

Error is correct you must return a function in testdb fn

Should be

```js
// routings.js
function testdb() {
  const fs = require("fs")
  const path = require("path")
  const testing = require(path.resolve(
    "./includes/database/createConnection.js"
  ))

  let connection = testing.connectToDatabase()
  connection.query("SELECT GETDATE()", function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error

    return results[0].solution
  })
  console.log("Got through")
  return (req, res) => {
    res.send("123")
  }
}

module.exports = { testdb }
```

Reference on how to use middlewares: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html , take a look to **"Router-level middleware"**

Comment: This will get rid of the error, but it doesn't help obtain `results[0].solution` which is what it looks like the OP wants.